# MacBook Pro Audio Jack Delay

Tags: macos, audio, macbook-pro

I have the MacBook Pro & Retina(2012s) running on Mavericks, both seem to be exhibiting a delay when headphone/speaker is connected to the Audio Jack. I've read the thread on the apple forums and it seems this is a normal event, but I find it very intruding especially when I switch sources from headphones to speakers at outdoors.

But, while using bootcamp this delay doesn't seem to occur and I guess all these are managed at kernel/OS level.

The reason stated at the forums was quite inadequate, because the smartphones today have similar jacks (Audio In/Out) and the switching happens quite fast.

Would like to know if it was possible to tweak this event.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar issue on my 2012 retina display MacBook Pro.  Since the latest update 10.9.4 there has been a delay in the volume adjustments for both the speakers and headphone jack when using the volume buttons on the keyboard. The delay is of 3 or 4 seconds. I can bypass this delay using the volume adjustment on my menu bar at the top right of my screen.